# In Android, how to measure the data traffic per interface per application

Tags: android, traffic-measurement

I want to implement an extention to `android.net.TrafficStats` to measure the data traffic per APN or per APN per application. the methods prototype looks like:

```
getInterfaceTxPackets(String interface)
getInterfaceRxPackets(String interface)
getInterfaceTxBytes(String interface)
getInterfaceRxBytes(String interface)
getUidInterfaceTxPackets(int uid,String interface)
getUidInterfaceRxPackets(int uid,String interface)
getUidInterfaceTxBytes(int uid,String interface)
getUidInterfaceRxBytes(int uid,String interface)
```

I read the `android.net.TrafficStats.java`, it call the native methods in `android_net_TrafficStats.cpp`, and the native methods read the traffic statistics from some files:

- the total traffic statistic files are in folder `/sys/class/net/`, in this folder there are some sub folders like: eth0, ip6tnl0, rmnet0, rmnet1, rmnet2, rmnet3., the detailed statistic files are saved in these folders.
- the per application traffic statistic files are in `/proc/uid_stat/[uid]/`

My questions:

1. Do the folder `rmnet0, rmnet1, rmnet2, rmnet3..`.  match each APN? If do, what's the match rule? if don't, how can I get each APN traffic statistic?
2. In folder `/proc/uid_stat/[uid]/,` there are only two files: `tcp_rcv` and `tcp_snd`, how can I get each applicaton on each APN traffic stats?

Comment: Are you on ICS? In my opinion, application traffic stats are available only on ICS, see http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html#data-dev

Comment: I have found NetworkStatsFactory.java on ICS which can meet this requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please switch over to Android 4.0, where for the data usage monitoring this has been beefed up.  These APIs now sit on top of a much more complicated service that collects per-interface per-uid traffic information.

Note that there is no meaning associated with each of the interface names, so you can't just assume that a particular name you find on one device means the same thing on another.